# I want to remove any hash tags from any text

Tags: javascript

How I con to remove any hash tags (`#`) from my text by JS?
Example :

```
'1- #hello world #this my #script"
```

result without `#` :

```
'1- hello world this my script"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Javascript string replacement? google it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method in conjunction with a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

So you would need to do something like this:

```js
var foo = "1- #hello world #this my #script";

foo = foo.replace(/#/gm, "");

console.log(foo);
```

It is important to have a RegExp with that `g` flag, as a simple string replacement like this: `foo.replace("#", "")` would only replace the first occurrence.

Also, the `m` flag makes it so it works on multiple lines as well.

Comment: @AliEbrahim no problem, that's what we're here for. But next time please try googling it first.